# Switching Views between two tables of the same schema in runtime in Oracle

Tags: oracle, view, switching

My client has two tables that have identical columns, I'll call them T1 and T2.

One view, V points to T1, while some batch process works on T2. T2 has to be truncated and data reloaded afresh. T1 had the latest data before the new reloading on T2

When the batch is completed the View is replaced with V pointing to the T2 table. This switch takes place back and forth once a day.

My questions are:

1. When create or replace VIEW V for T2; is done switching V to point to T2 instead of T1 and concurrent queries to Oracle accessing V keeps coming in either by using SQL or a stored procedure, concurrently with modification of VIEW V , will there be a point where at the time of switching a query may fail.
2. Is there a better design where instead of VIEW V switching between tables the data can be reloaded as well as read at the same time.

Comment: I don't get your design but you may have a look at MATERIALIZED VIEWs

Comment: I'd avoid this 'truncate/load/switch' like the plague.  What is the rational for it?  How long does it take to load the table?  Can't that be done during off hours?  Or use a staging table.  Where is the data originating from, before it is loaded into one of the tables?

Comment: Materialised view is not an option for me. I do get your point. I will have to carry forward this in MySQL. Materialized view and on demand refresh would be needed there.

Comment: To Ed Stevens comment how would my end users read my data even while data is reloaded. The site has to run 24*7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a similar process in my company.  This is handled by using synonyms rather than a view, for example:

```
create or replace synonym tab_syn for user_tables; -- syn set-up for the process
select count(*) from tab_syn;                      -- run your process 
create or replace synonym tab_syn for all_tables;  -- syn next run
select count(*) from tab_syn;                      -- next run
```